# Internet Explorer won't fit exact measurements

Tags: internet-explorer, html

I am using a feature box on the homepage of my site that has a nivo slider sitting next to a registration form. The width of the slider is 701 and the form 255 making the whole div 956px. This displays these elements tight next to each other. This works perfect in Chrome and Firefox but with internet explorer it only works on occassion. Most of the time IE spreads it out all over the page as if it can't fit. Whats that about. The only way I have been able to make it work is to widen it by 1px. But I would rather not have this small gap in between. Does any one know why IE does this?

Comment: Oh and how to solve it please!

Comment: Could you post some screenshots?

Comment: My mind-reading and remote-code analyses satellite is current on loan to **NASA**.  Could you provide a *minimal* test case to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score -1):

There's no better way to say it: IE act that way cause it sucks!

Anyway, as long as MS won't fix their browser, we, the web developers, should make IE fixes, as described here: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer

Hope it helps :)